# Jenkins - get latest artifact with curl

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've been looking around and cannot find how to download the latest artifact with curl or even just to know the link.

I've discovered the permalinks and api xml/json feeds which contain all the data that is needed such as the artifact names etc....Also discovered the special link that zips all artifacts, but my artifact is already zipped.

Is there is a way to not have to pick out information and just use a simple link. In other words, tell jenkins to give me the latest artifact of job x without specifying filenames etc... such as:

jenkinsserver:8080/job/job_name/lastbuild/artifactdownload

Any help would be appreciated. Thank-you

EDIT: 
Should have mentioned that the name of the artifact contains the version number, such as: artifact.xx.xx.xx.zip

Answer (score 5):

You have to do a get on

http://localhost:9091/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json

then you parse that looking for artifacts array then look at relativePath and do another get on the actual artifact

http://localhost:9091/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/WHAT_EVER_ARTIFACT

Comment: What if the artifact is nested in a dir ex:  http://localhost:9091/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/SOME_DIR/WHAT_EVER_ARTIFACT

Comment: If it is a multi-branch pipeline (type) job, you need the branch as well, like this:
`http://localhost:9091/job/JOB_NAME/job/BRANCH_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an option to achieve this:

```
https://jenkinsserver.com/job/<job-name>/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/<Artifact-Name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't give me the download link. It gives me the html page...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Werner The URL string **is** the answer.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, but <Artifact-Name> would be dynamic with the version number in the filename and therefore not known. Looking for a link that would give me the artifact without knowing the name of file..if that is even possible in Jenkins...

Answer (score 1):

I think most proper URL should be:

Current LTS stable
https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/latestCore.txt

Current main branch:
https://updates.jenkins.io/current/latestCore.txt

Comment: The poster asked about getting the latest artifacts of a job and not about the Jenkins core updates