# Generate an URL Of an artifact to download from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sbt

I am trying to generate a link for a user to download a build artifact (WAR for maven and ZIP for SBT) from Jenkins after a successful build. I could not figure it out but I found that I have to write a small ant script which can generate an url to download an artifact.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269922/jenkins-get-latest-artifact-with-curl has a good answer by @lfmunoz

Answer (score 2):

You can download directly from workspace

```
http://<Jenkins URL>:<Jenkins>/job/Test/ws/<location of artifact>/xyz.zip
```

or from Last stable build

```
http://<URL>:<PORT>/job/Test/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/xzy.zip
```

or from Last build

```
http://<Jenkins URL>:<Jenkins>/job/Test/lastBuild/artifact/xzy.zip
```

If there is authentication

```
curl -X POST --user usernme:API_Token http://<Jenkins URL>:<Jenkins>/job/Test/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/xzy.zip -o xzy.zip
```

All these links are permanent and will not change

Comment: To find available artifacts, one can use the JSON API: `http://localhost:9091/job/JOB_NAME/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`

Comment: I had to enable "artifact archiving" of my WAR file as a "post-build action". Now I can download my WAR file