# How can I find out the latest stable Jenkins version via API call?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I'm trying to write a script that creates a Docker image from a Jenkins image, that is, the first line of my Dockerfile is...

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.249.3
```

However I wanna be smart and write a script that gets the latest Jenkins stable version and sed that into my Dockerfile, like this

```
Dockerfile:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER

$ export JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER=`some_api_call`
$ sed -i "s/JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER/$JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER/g" Dockerfile
$ docker build ...
```

What is "some_api_call"?

Comment: The "latest LTS" is always available from: https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war. [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins) also says: "To use the latest LTS: `docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts` "

Comment: That's useful, thanks. But I NEED the actual version. However I will play with that idea.

Comment: I don't know if this helps or will help for long as [the site LAYOUT.md](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/update-center2/blob/master/site/LAYOUT.md#regular-tiered-update-sites-lts-and-weekly) flags it as *(Unused, may be removed)* , but you could read the file `latestCore.txt` to get the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

latest stable:

`curl -L  --max-redirs 2  https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/latestCore.txt`

latest current:

`curl -L  --max-redirs 2  https://updates.jenkins.io/current/latestCore.txt`

Comment: Finally, after all this time, THE answer I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Ian's comment

https://updates.jenkins.io/current/latestCore.txt

https://updates.jenkins.io/stable/latestCore.txt

is one way to get the latest version, but read through the document in that comment.

I also found this answer which agrees

[Jenkins - get latest artifact with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269922/jenkins-get-latest-artifact-with-curl)