# How can I get the latest Jenkins version via API call?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a script that creates a Docker image using a Jenkins image as base, that is, the first line of my Dockerfile is...

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.249.3
```

However I wanna be smart and write a script that gets the latest Jenkins stable version and sed that into my Dockerfile, like this

```
Dockerfile:
FROM jenkins/jenkins:JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER

$ export JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER=`some_api_call`
$ sed -i "s/JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER/$JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER/g" Dockerfile
$ docker build -t docker_url/jenkins:$JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER .
$ docker push docker_url/jenkins:$JENKINS_LATEST_STABLE_VER
```

I'm aware of `jenkins/jenkins:lts` but I NEED the actual version number, e.g., 2.249.3. What is "some_api_call" ?

Comment: why do you want to use the version always? any specific reason?

Comment: Several reasons. I want to keep different versions of Jenkins, I want to be able to pick and choose the specific version of Jenkins on other scripts, etc. I don't alway want to use the "latest."

Comment: I think you can get the list of tags from the registry and parse the results to get the latest: https://hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/jenkins/jenkins/tags. Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28320134/11073431)

Comment: I marked this as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794761/how-can-i-find-out-the-latest-stable-jenkins-version-via-api-call

Answer (score 0):

I saw [this post](https://kublr.com/blog/advanced-jenkins-groovy-scripting-for-live-fetching-of-docker-images/), and tried this. However it returns Alpine images, but I need CentOS ones. For the life of me I can't figure out the URL for the Centos images? I essentially want to get [this list](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags?page_size=20&page=1&ordering=last_updated).

```
// Import the JsonSlurper class to parse Dockerhub API response
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
// Set the URL we want to read from, it is MySQL from official Library for this example, limited to 20 results only.
// docker_image_tags_url = "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mysql/tags/?page_size=20"
docker_image_tags_url = "https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/jenkins/tags?page_size=30"
try {
    // Set requirements for the HTTP GET request, you can add Content-Type headers and so on...
    def http_client = new URL(docker_image_tags_url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    http_client.setRequestMethod('GET')
    // Run the HTTP request
    http_client.connect()
    // Prepare a variable where we save parsed JSON as a HashMap, it's good for our use case, as we just need the 'name' of each tag.
    def dockerhub_response = [:]    
    // Check if we got HTTP 200, otherwise exit
    if (http_client.responseCode == 200) {
        dockerhub_response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(http_client.inputStream.getText('UTF-8'))
    } else {
        println("HTTP response error")
        System.exit(0)
    }
    // Prepare a List to collect the tag names into
    def image_tag_list = []
    // Iterate the HashMap of all Tags and grab only their "names" into our List
    dockerhub_response.results.each { tag_metadata ->
        image_tag_list.add(tag_metadata.name)    
    }
    // The returned value MUST be a Groovy type of List or a related type (inherited from List)
    // It is necessary for the Active Choice plugin to display results in a combo-box
    return image_tag_list.sort()
} catch (Exception e) {
         // handle exceptions like timeout, connection errors, etc.
         println(e)
}
```